# can I put this cable inside the wall to hide it

Tags: electrical, wiring, cables

Theres this cable popping out of my wall and it looks ugly, i bought a cover and was wondering if it should be ok to just push this cable inside the wall and close it with the cover[image]

Comment: If the box is covered, why would it matter if the cable is pushed inside the wall or not?

Comment: Fernanda Ribeiro, Tip, consider trimming the coax and center conductor so they do not touch.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can cover that box with a cover without any issues, and paint it to match the wall if you so desire.  Regardless of what type of wire it is, code permits this.

If you wanted to actually remove the box and permanently cover the hole, you'd want to be more certain about what the wire is and where it comes from.  It appears to be coax, which could connect anywhere in the house, or could connect to an old antenna (TV or radio), or a variety of other places.